# How can I share a binary among tasks?

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

Let's say that I have some kind of binary that I want to share among all tasks (containing a trained ML model, for instance). How can I do so using the `DataStream` API?

While I understand there's the concept of [broadcast variables](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/dev/batch/#broadcast-variables) in the `DataSet` API, it seems there is no equivalent for streaming.

I thought maybe I could have a custom data source that emits a single value (the `Serializable` I want to share, which is captured by Flink inside a closure) and registers it as Queryable State using a `ValueStateDescriptor`. Would this be a viable option?

I'm looking for something similar to [Spark's shared variables](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/rdd-programming-guide.html#broadcast-variables) so that I can allow "clients" of the stuff I'm building to use a given shared variable inside the lambdas they pass to "my" operators (that essentially are an abstraction on top of Flink and other engines).

**Edit:** queryable state is not an option given that it must be keyed.

Comment: Are you trying to share this across all parallel instances of a particular operator, or across all instances of all operators? And is the shared value going to evolve while the job is running?

Comment: @DavidAnderson across all instances of all operators and the value won't change.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of ways to approach this using Flink's DataStream API. One is to use [rich functions](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.5/dev/api_concepts.html#rich-functions), and load/initialize the shared data in the `open()` method. If the value won't change, this should work fine. Another approach is to use [broadcast state](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.5/dev/stream/state/broadcast_state.html) to distribute the shared data wherever it's needed.

A typical streaming application that needs to apply a trained ML model will use some stateful operators to compute the features, and then feed the assembled feature vector into a `RichFlatMap` that has loaded the model.

Comment: I don't think using rich functions is a very good solution when using a large binary considering that I a priori don't know which operator will have to use it, I'm afraid that it would incur in too much I/O between the driver and the task managers. Will probably be going the queryable state route so that I can at least load it lazily.

Comment: Can you edit your original question and provide more of an explanation? I don't understand what you are trying to do. How is it that you don't know beforehand which operator(s) will need this binary data, and why then can't they load it at the point they learn that they need it? If it's static data, it doesn't need to be managed by Flink at all. Can't you simply load the data into a private transient variable of the operators that need it?